# Find consecutive 12 month rolling periods based on a condition

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a calculator to identify the earliest finish date with 5 consecutive 12 month rolling periods which satisfy a specific condition (absence less than 180 days in my example)

The code starts with a fixed start date and adds 12 months to calculate the absence period in any given window. If the absence period is greater than 180 days, it should adjust the start date so the absence is less than 180 days and continue till 5 such consecutive periods are found

I can think of the brute force solution but would love to know any more elegant solutions.

```cs
    public void CalculateAbsence()
    {
        var startDate = new LocalDate(2018, 5, 5);
        var qualifyinYears = 0;

        while (qualifyinYears < 5)
        {
            var totalAbsence = 0;
            var endDate = startDate.PlusYears(1);
            //Retrieve All applicable absences in this qualifying Period
            foreach (var abs in Immigration.ApplicableAbsences(startDate, endDate))
            {
                totalAbsence += Period.DaysBetween((abs.Start < startDate ? startDate : abs.Start), (abs.End > endDate ? endDate : abs.End));
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Year {startDate}-{endDate}. Absence: {totalAbsence}");
            qualifyinYears++;
            startDate = startDate.PlusYears(1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have code that works so you have no actual problem. You're basically asking for someone to provide a more efficient algorithm. Not a C# question and not a .NET question. Probably not a question for SO at all. It's a legitimate question for a programmer but it would probably be better asked elsewhere.

Comment: A simple enhancement, if you're increasing the start date by one day each step, try increasing it by the maximum difference between totalAbsence and 180 among the windows

Comment: So you have `totalAbsence` for each year, and now you want to calculate a running total and stop when the total over any 5 years is <=180? The process will be similar to a moving average, without the divide. You need to track the last 5 values so you can subtract them again.

Comment: There's some ambiguity in the way you worded your question. What I think you are asking for is to find the earliest `startDate`, which could be any date on the calendar. Where the following 5x12 month periods each have <=180 days of absences. Though 180/365 days of absence sounds like a lot.